# Has anyone released an app using PixateFreestyle

Tags: ios, iphone, pixate

I know this may come across as something that could be discussed - but am asking a very specific question.

I need to implement theming in an application I am working on.  [PixateFreestyle](http://www.freestyle.org) looks like the most promising solution as we could just style it all using CSS.  My question is:

- Has anyone released an app to the store successfully using PixateFreestyle, and if so, were there any potential app-review related issues I should be cautious of?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two apps that have been in the App Store for several months, and both include Pixate Freestyle. I have done multiple releases of each app and have not had any issues with Apple's reviewers.

I think Freestyle is pretty safe.